# How to set JavaScript object's array in elements attribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object and I want to save it as attribute's value in an element. I write following code:

```js
var objArr = [
  { 
    class: "level-0", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-1", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-2", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-3", 
    style: undefined 
  }
];

$(".temp-div").attr('div-properties', objArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="temp-div">
Temp div here
</div>
```

which generate

```
<div class="temp-div" div-properties="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">
Temp div here
</div>
```

I am trying to get

```
<div class="temp-div" div-properties="[{class: "level-0",style: undefined},{class: "level-1",style: undefined},{class: "level-2",style: undefined},{class: "level-3",style: undefined}]">
Temp div here
</div>
```

as output. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` is probably what you're after (you're currently inadvertently using `.toString()`). `JSON.stringify` will remove your `undefined` pairs because they aren't valid JSON values, so there's some footwork done to preserve them artificially.

```js
var objArr = [
  { 
    class: "level-0", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-1", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-2", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-3", 
    style: undefined 
  }
];

const stringified = JSON.stringify(
  objArr, (k, v) => v === undefined ? "undefined" : v
).replace(/"undefined"/g, "undefined");

$(".temp-div").attr('div-properties', stringified);

console.log(stringified); // testing 1-2
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="temp-div">
Temp div here
</div>
```

Consider replacing undefined with `null` to produce a valid, parseable JSON string. Here's how you might go about reviving such a structure:

```js
var objArr = [
  { 
    class: "level-0", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-1", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-2", 
    style: undefined 
  },
  { 
    class: "level-3", 
    style: undefined 
  }
];

const stringified = JSON.stringify(
  objArr, (k, v) => v === undefined ? null : v
);

$(".temp-div").attr('div-properties', stringified);

/* ... later on in your code ... */
const parsed = JSON.parse($('.temp-div').attr('div-properties')); 

parsed.forEach(e => 
  Object.keys(e).forEach(f => e[f] = e[f] === null ? undefined : e[f])
);

console.log(parsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="temp-div">
Temp div here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Except that "undefined" is not a valid JSON value, and it can't be easily parsed back from this JSON. "null" is. But yes, JSON.stringify is a way to go.

Comment: Yes, I should have emphasized that more. This may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1):

First off I would advise against this if this data is used elsewhere, there are far better data structures (like an Array of Objects). Having said that, an attribute is always a string, so you need to convert the data into a string with JSON.stringify() and then use `.data()` to create a `data-*` attribute.

### Demo

```js
var objArr = [{
  class: "level-0",
  style: void 0
}, {
  class: "level-1",
  style: void 0
}, {
  class: "level-2",
  style: void 0
}, {
  class: "level-3",
  style: void 0
}];

$('.temp-div').data('prop', JSON.stringify(objArr));

console.log($('.temp-div').data('prop'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="temp-div">
  Temp div here
</div>
```

Comment: can you recommend me best data structure which can be stored as attribute in element.

Comment: That object isn't useful in a tag. If you handle it as it is, you can save yourself a few steps: 1.find the tag in DOM, 2. Access the data from tag, 3.parse the data so it's an object again. 4. Do you know if that array was needed anywhere else while it sat in DOM Purgatory?